# Creating Cypher query engine to automatically generate queries

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to generate queries in cypher from given parameters
For example user gives needs students who are male and and in certain class
Lets say i got two variables gender and class. How can i generate queries from this if there are more parameters and all parameters are optional

I tried to create atomic queries and running them individually and getteing the common. But this is very slow

Comment: What about using `coalesce`?

Comment: @jvx8ss i do not need just one but all the rows in the result